# Math formula(s) to get non-regular triangles vertex Cx and Cy coordinates if I know everything all

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I know Ax and Ay, Bx and By coordinates of triangle. I know the sizes of all three sides AB, BC, CA. With these inputs I can get all angles of A B C vertex. But I would like to get the Cx and Cy coordinates of the third point C. Which math formula return the most accurate result with non 90 degree, non equilateral triangles? I trying to implement formulas to programming langiage, but sometimes I got inaccurate bad results.

[Image with result what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc8eP.jpg)

The image is a real example. I have all data, but I would like to get as result Cx = 70; Cy = 30; with the most accurate math formula.

Thanks for help!

Comment: To clarify - you're given the coordinates of two vertices as well as the side lengths of a triangle and you're looking for the coordinates of the third vertex? What do you mean by 'most accurate'?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get no more than the X Y coordinates of vertex C. The result what I need is visible on the picture (70/30) but I need universal formula what I can use all type of triangles (for example sharp and wide). I mean, if the result is integer, for example 70/30 in this situation, I would like to get integer too, or very closed floating number. But not 71.54875/27.02548.

Comment: What programming language is this? As far as I can see, precision shouldn't make that much of a difference in most cases.

Comment: I have to implement more than one programming language. I think precision is not the failure of the language I use, I have no really good math formula. and I have to convert values between units, but before I do it I would like to found the best formula.

Comment: What is the current method you are using to calculate the coordinates?

Comment: I know I have two result. But no problem. I deleted the wrong formulas. Now I have only one, but useful only for 90 degrees triangles:  $Cy = (pow($AB, 2) + pow($AC, 2) - pow($BC, 2)) / ($AB * 2);
$Cx = sqrt(abs(pow($AC, 2) - pow($Cy, 2))); but I need universal formula for all types of triangles.

Comment: Do you want both of the possibilities for $C$ or any one of them from the formula? (I mistakenly said $4$ earlier). Or on the other hand, do you know that $\triangle ABC$ is labelled in that order clockwise?

Comment: In this situation all vertex coordinates can be only positive. This is the reason we using abs() on the upper formula.

Comment: That still allows for two possibilities depending on if you label $\triangle ABC$ clockwise or anti-clockwise

Comment: We have always 2 points A and B with known coordinates. The point C is the unknown vertex. I think I can use only one direction for more simple formula and for only one xy result.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}{AC}^2=(C_x-A_x)^2+(C_y-A_y)^2\\\\{BC}^2=(C_x-B_x)^2+(C_y-B_y)^2\end{cases}$$

$\implies$

$${AC}^2 - {BC}^2=2(-A_x+B_x)C_x+2(-A_y+B_y)C_y+A_x^2+A_y^2-B_x^2-B_y^2$$

$\implies$

$$(A_x-B_x)C_x+(A_y-B_y)C_y=\frac{(A_x^2+A_y^2-B_x^2-B_y^2) - ({AC}^2-{BC}^2)}{2}$$

Now,

$$\begin{cases}(A_y-B_y)^2{AC}^2=(A_y-B_y)^2(C_x-A_x)^2+((A_y-B_y)C_y-(A_y-B_y)A_y)^2\\\\(A_x-B_x)^2{AC}^2=((A_x-B_x)C_x-(A_x-B_x)A_x)^2+(A_x-B_x)^2(C_y-A_y)^2\end{cases}$$

$\implies$

$$\begin{cases}(A_y-B_y)^2{AC}^2=(A_y-B_y)^2(C_x-A_x)^2+(\frac{1}{2}((A_x^2+A_y^2-B_x^2-B_y^2)-({AC}^2-{BC}^2))-(A_x-B_x)C_x-(A_y-B_y)A_y)^2\\\\(A_x-B_x)^2{AC}^2=(\frac{1}{2}((A_x^2+A_y^2-B_x^2-B_y^2)-({AC}^2-{BC}^2))-(A_y-B_y)C_y-(A_x-B_x)A_x)^2+(A_x-B_x)^2(C_y-A_y)^2\end{cases}$$

Now you have quadratics in $C_x$ and $C_y$ you can solve.

For convenience, let $p=\frac{1}{2}((A_x^2+A_y^2-B_x^2-B_y^2)-({AC}^2-{BC}^2))-(A_y-B_y)A_y$ and $q=\frac{1}{2}((A_x^2+A_y^2-B_x^2-B_y^2)-({AC}^2-{BC}^2))-(A_x-B_x)A_x$.

Then we have

$$\begin{cases}(A_y-B_y)^2{AC}^2=(A_y-B_y)^2(C_x-A_x)^2+(p-(A_x-B_x)C_x)^2\\\\(A_x-B_x)^2{AC}^2=(q-(A_y-B_y)C_y)^2+(A_x-B_x)^2(C_y-A_y)^2\end{cases}$$

$\implies$

$$\begin{cases}(A_y-B_y)^2{AC}^2=(A_y-B_y)^2(C_x^2-2A_xC_x+A_x^2)+(p^2-2p(A_x-B_x)C_x+(A_x-B_x)^2C_x^2)\\\\(A_x-B_x)^2{AC}^2=(q^2-2q(A_y-B_y)C_y+(A_y-B_y)^2C_y^2)+(A_x-B_x)^2(C_y^2-2A_yC_y+A_y^2)\end{cases}$$

$\implies$

$$\begin{cases}((A_x-B_x)^2+(A_y-B_y)^2)C_x^2+(-2A_x(A_y−B_y)^2-2p(A_x−B_x))C_x+(p^2+(A_y−B_y)^2A_x^2-(A_y−B_y)^2{AC}^2)=0\\\\((A_x-B_x)^2+(A_y-B_y)^2)C_y^2+(−2A_y(A_x−B_x)^2−2q(A_y−B_y))C_y+(q^2+(A_x−B_x)^2A_y^2−(A_x−B_x)^2{AC}^2)=0\end{cases}$$

$\implies$

$$\begin{cases}((A_x-B_x)^2+(A_y-B_y)^2)C_x^2-2(A_x(A_y−B_y)^2+p(A_x−B_x))C_x+(p^2+(A_y−B_y)^2(A_x^2-{AC}^2))=0\\\\((A_x-B_x)^2+(A_y-B_y)^2)C_y^2-2(A_y(A_x−B_x)^2+q(A_y−B_y))C_y+(q^2+(A_x−B_x)^2(A_y^2−{AC}^2))=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for this very long formula. I will try to solve them to Cx and Cy. But maybe the formula can be easier and shorter if all input and output coordinates most be positive?

Comment: @PerjésLászló The coordinates being positive does not make a difference

Comment: Not just all coordinates must be in positive area, because I always have measured value of side length AC and BC, if I change the vertex label from A to B, the point of C not changed because the side length will be changed too. Think I right?

Comment: Unfortunately not succeed to solve this formula to Cx and Cy :( Could you help me for this please?

Comment: You use the quadratic formula? Everything else that isn't $C_x$ or $C_y$ are known constants

Comment: I dont know how to use  quadratic formula for this solution.

Comment: The quadratic formula says $ax^2+bx+c=0\iff x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ for $a\neq 0$. Substitute $C_x$ for $x$ and then write the equations so they are in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Comment: Substitution of x to Cx is ok, but how to substitute a, b, and c in this formula with my known constants?

Comment: If you multiply out the equation, you should be able to group 'like' terms in $C_x^2, C_x$. Then you set $a,b,c$ to the coefficients ($c$ being the constants)

Comment: @PerjésLászló Edited in

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the coordinates of $A,B$ is known as well as distances $a,b,c$
and vertices  $A,B,C$
are ordered clockwise as in the picture,
[image]

we can calculate the area $S$ of $\triangle ABC$
and the angle $\alpha=\angle BAC$.
Hence we can get the altitude $h_c=\frac{2S}c$
and $|AH_c|=b\,\cos\alpha$. 
Given that, the coordinates of $H_c$

\begin{align}
H_c&=A\,(1-\tfrac{b}c\,\cos\alpha)+B\,\tfrac{b}c\,\cos\alpha
.
\end{align}

To get the coordinates of $C$, we need to add a vector 
$\overrightarrow{H_cC}\perp \overrightarrow{BA}:|H_cC|=h_c$:

\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{H_cC}
&=
\tfrac{h_c}c\,(B_y-A_y,A_x-B_x)
.
\end{align}

In numbers:

\begin{align}
S&=825
;\\
\cos\alpha&=0.53687549219316
;\\
c&=31.6227766016838
;\\
h_c&=52.1775813927783
;\\
H_c&=(20.5,46.5)
;\\
\overrightarrow{H_cC}
&=(49.5,-16.5)
;\\
C&=H_c+\overrightarrow{H_cC}=(70.30)
.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I checked and implemented, and I have very good results! Thanks again!

Comment: @Perjés László: Welcome to MSE.
You can help other people
who will possibly have a similar question in the future
by accepting the useful answer (by clicking on the checkmark).

You can also have a look at 
[the starter tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
to familiarize yourself further with the format.

Comment: Thank you, certainly I accepted your answer, but not counted.